# How to mark unreachable cases in pattern matching

Tags: haskell

What is the standard way to "mark" unreachable cases in pattern-matching expression? For example, with Aeson, I have Value and need to unpack it. I do it with pattern matching and I know that it's Object and it's not Array, String, Number, etc, because I created it. So, I will have case like `_ -> something`. What must be `something`? I mean standard Haskell, not LiquidHaskell approaches :)  Is it something like `error "Internal error"` or something else?

Comment: For Aeson, I suggest you use `withObject` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.3.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:withObject. In case you want to handle it yourself, for `Aeson` the idea is to `typeMismatch expected v`. Such that the parser can provide a useful error in case it goes wrong anyway.

Comment: After all, usually the idea is to see functions as independent building stones. So one function does not provide much context to another. Each function should aim to implement the specifications as complete as possible I would say (so a "total" approach).

Comment: It's not parsing. I get representation of some entity with `toJSON something` then I want to add field to the resulting record (HashMap), so I unpack `Value` (expect it as `Object`) and insert other field (`HM.insert addKey addValue myObj`). So, I know that `toJSON something` returns `Value` with `Object` term but when I pattern-matching on it, I need to write something for other constructors (terms)

Comment: As mentioned above, there are Aeson-specific solutions.  In general you either a) rework the types to eliminate the unused pattern or 2) Use something like `error "Impossible: blah blah blah"`.

Comment: @Paul-AG You should still handle the "impossible" case gracefully so that your code can be used in other contexts. For instance if some day someone wants to actually parse real JSON from a text file, they are going to want to have the typeMismatch calls included as per Willem Van Onsem's comment.

Answer (score 9):

Having impossible constructors is a common occurrence in Haskell and can/is handled one of two ways depending on the situation and the style.  Many developers, especially those who favor a Haskell 98 style of code, will simply indicate the impossible cases via an error:

```
data SumType1 = ConstrA | ConstrB | ConstrC

anyConstr :: SumType1 -> Int
anyConstr ConstrA = 1
anyConstr ConstrB = 2
anyConstr ConstrC = 3

onlyConstrA :: SumType1 -> Int
onlyConstrA ConstrA = 1
onlyConstrA _ = error "Impossible: internal error, passed wrong constructor."
```

However, this is both unsatisfying and requiring the developer to ensure safety when the compiler is capable and much more reliable.  The common solution is to use a type that can only represent ConstrA.  You could have the `SumType1` be a sum of two types one of which has a field that is "ConstrAType" but that sort of refactoring can be really draining.  Sometimes I prefer a GADT solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

data SumTag = A | Anything
data SumType (a :: SumTag) where
     ConstrA :: SumType A
     ConstrB :: SumType Anything
     ConstrC :: SumType Anything

doAnything :: SumType a -> Int
doAnything ConstrA = 1
doAnything ConstrB = 2
doAnything ConstrC = 3

onlyConstrA :: SumType A -> Int
onlyConstrA ConstrA = 1
```

Now the function `onlyConstrA` has a type that clearly shows (when considered in conjunction with the data declaration) it can only be applied to the `ConstrA` constructor.  At the same time we haven't lost any power, for example `doAnything` doesn't need to consider a hairy bisection of the original SumType1 into various types - the constructors are all from the same original type.